# A good example in hadoop that needs iteration

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am currently implement a parallel-for on hadoop to iterate the mapper a number of times as specify by the user. Can someone help me with a useful example that I can use my implementation for testing. Some application in Hadoop that needs iteration of the Mapper function.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you exactly mean by "iteration of the mapper"? I have an example of starting a job recursively (on the input of the last job).

Have a look here, it explains a simple graph mindist-search / graph exploration algorithm: http://codingwiththomas.blogspot.com/2011/04/graph-exploration-with-hadoop-mapreduce.html

A bit more generic version is this here:
http://codingwiththomas.blogspot.com/2011/04/controlling-hadoop-job-recursion.html

Answer (score 2):

The simplest one is implementing [Apriori](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm) algorithm which is used to find the frequent itemset.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of examples in data mining. You could try one of the clustering algorithms, for example.